# How can I wire this switched GFCI combo outlet with two neutrals and two hot wires?

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle, gfci

I’d like to wire a switched GFCI combo such that the switch controls the GFCI plug. I found this diagram for doing so:

[image: wiring diagram]

This looks easy enough. However, after unscrewing the current outlet, I’m seeing there are two hot wires and two neutral wires (and one ground):

[image: current wiring]

My house was built in 1948.

What do I do with the extra hot and extra neutral wire?

And, is there a difference between the two neutrals or a difference between the two hots?

Comment: When you trip the GFCI, does anything else lose power?

Comment: Is the existing receptacle a standard receptacle or a GFCI? (It appears to be the latter from the back, but I can't tell for sure from here)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can clearly see LOAD and LINE on the back. It’s a GFCI.

Comment: Yes it’s a GFCI.

Answer (score 6):

If you look carefully at your old outlet, you’ll see that there is embossed on the outlet “line” near one pair and “load” near the other.

The line wires are the power feed and the load wires run onto more outlet and/or lights that are also protected by the GFCI.

If you want, you can connect the load wires to the load terminals of the new GFCI. However, then whatever is there will also be controlled by the switch.

To avoid controlling those by the switch, you’ll need to connect the two pairs together. However, that will remove the protection from whatever is downstream and you’ll need to add one or more additional GFCIs to replace that protection.

You may want the trip off the current GFCI to see what else loses power. It could be another bathroom or even garage or outdoor outlets.